# Android 8.1/9.0 removeView(View) is not supported in AdapterView

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter, android-adapterview

I'm getting a "removeView(View) is not supported in AdapterView" exception when running my app in Android version 8.1 and 9.0. In previous versions it runs fine. Although the error is consistent it doesn't happen 100% of the time (which makes me suspect it's a threading issue) nor is it specific to a particular adapter or list view. For instance, I access the same code from multiple actives and it works fine for some and always fails for others. I should also point out that I'm not calling removeView in any of the situations where I get the error. Below is the LogCat output for the exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: removeView(View) is not supported in AdapterView
    at android.widget.AdapterView.removeView(AdapterView.java:531)
    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.add(ViewOverlay.java:195)
    at android.view.ViewGroupOverlay.add(ViewGroupOverlay.java:72)
    at android.transition.TransitionUtils.createViewBitmap(TransitionUtils.java:170)
    at android.transition.TransitionUtils.copyViewImage(TransitionUtils.java:104)
    at android.transition.Visibility.onDisappear(Visibility.java:380)
    at android.transition.Visibility.createAnimator(Visibility.java:249)
    at android.transition.Transition.createAnimators(Transition.java:732)
    at android.transition.TransitionSet.createAnimators(TransitionSet.java:396)
    at android.transition.Transition.playTransition(Transition.java:1779)
    at android.transition.TransitionManager$MultiListener.onPreDraw(TransitionManager.java:315)
    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:977)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2349)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1392)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6752)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Can anyone point me towards a solution?

Comment: did you solve it

Comment: Same problem, 0 information anywhere on the net how to solve or what causes.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up subclassing ListView and overrode removeView and addView with empty methods. I doubt this is the correct way to fix this problem but it worked.